# Java number format - #.## - Windows and Linux

Tags: java, windows, linux, number-formatting

I'm using following code to format Double number

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat=new DecimalFormat("#.##");
decimalFormat.format(1.04)
```

but this gives

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,04"
```

in Linux - but in Windows 7 this works fine, how to correct this?

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is being generated by the call to `format`? It looks like a message that comes from trying to parse rather than format.

Comment: This should not matter between Windows or Linux .. and 1.04 is a valid decimal value so that exception does not look correct

Comment: Valid decimal in ENGLISH locales :)

Comment: Double.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(1.04));                         this gives the  exception

Comment: @buddhi - what's your locale set to ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DecimalFormat and Double.valueOf()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691018/decimalformat-and-double-valueof)

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a very similar question answered here ( [DecimalFormat and Double.valueOf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691018/decimalformat-and-double-valueof) ) about the java number format. Basically the diference you are experiencing may be related to the Locale Settings defined on Windows being different to the Linux one (for example: on Windows you configured it to a contry/language different then the linux one).

Comment: I don't know what distro you are using, but I will give you the Ubuntu  wiki instructions that will probably be similar or the same you are using right now: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale Make sure all locale related variables are correctly defined. But also take a look of the suggestion on the link, as it seems to be more likely to be a permanent fix)

Comment: Are you using the same Locale in both W7 and Linux?