# Exception Java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java

I have :

```
DecimalFormat mydf = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

mydf.format(Double.parseDouble(item.getText(4)
.replaceAll(",", ""))
+ Double.parseDouble(item.getText(6)
.replaceAll(",", ""))
+ Double.parseDouble(item.getText(8)
.replaceAll(",", "")))
```

where, item' is a TableItem,which returns String and I get error when the 'item.getText' gives value '24,807,847.65'.
I thought Double could handle this number.

Comment: try using DecimalFormat("#,###.##");

Answer (score 1):

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691018/decimalformat-and-double-valueof).

The reason may be that you are using a localized format.