# NumberFormatException in Location.DistanceBetween result

Tags: android, gps, location, distance

i create location-based application. within the application there is a method to get user position. Some of users encountered that the app crash when trying to get user position. below is my get user position method.

```
// Method to get user position
public void getUserPosition(double latitude, double longitude){
    // Check distance between user position and default position
    Location.distanceBetween(latitude, longitude,
            mUtils.ARG_DEFAULT_LATITUDE, mUtils.ARG_DEFAULT_LONGITUDE, mCheckDistances);

    // If the distance is more than maximum distance, then use default position
    if (Double.valueOf(String.format("%.2f", (mCheckDistances[0] / 1000))) > mUtils.ARG_MAX_DISTANCE) {
        mCurrentLocation = new Location("");
        mCurrentLocation.setLatitude(mUtils.ARG_DEFAULT_LATITUDE);
        mCurrentLocation.setLongitude(mUtils.ARG_DEFAULT_LONGITUDE);
        mCurrentLatitude = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
        mCurrentLongitude = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();

        if(mLocationResultStatus == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
            showSnackbar(getString(R.string.gps_not_enabled_alert));
        }else {
            showSnackbar(getString(R.string.distance_alert));
        }

    }else{
        mCurrentLatitude = latitude;
        mCurrentLongitude = longitude;
    }

    // Move camera to user position
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(mCurrentLatitude, mCurrentLongitude),
            mUtils.ARG_DEFAULT_MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL);
    mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

}
```

and below is the error log,

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "12550,25"
at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:164)
at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:282)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:338)
at com.pongodev.locazee.activities.ActivityHome.getUserPosition(ActivityHome.java:675)
at com.pongodev.locazee.activities.ActivityHome.onLocationChanged(ActivityHome.java:1031)
at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzi$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

The error log says that Invalid double but the result of Location.distanceBetween is float. is there anyone can help me to fix this out? many thanks.

Comment: If (mCheckDistances[0] / 1000) already is an float an you use it in String.format("%.2f", ...) you get something strange like i.e. "10.5.2f"

Comment: Try using float instead of double

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the float to a double by doing `(double) floatName` but this will cause round-off error so don't expect precision.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error is with your value :  12550,25 
the value should be like 12550.25 not 12550,25.

If you want to convert any string to double, that string should contain only numbers and "." not anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a localization issue when formatting your string. Take a look at this post: [DecimalFormat and Double.valueOf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691018/decimalformat-and-double-valueof/2691163)